# Running equations by categories along a column in r

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns

I currently have a dataframe that looks like this

```
tree cookie height radius
C1T1   A     0.37   12.3
c1t1   B     0.65   14.2
C1T1   C     0.91   16
C1T2   A     0.2    4
C1T2   B     0.5    10
C1T2   C     0.75   12.4
```

I would like to add a "volume" column to this dataframe. The equation that would be in the volume column is: (1/3) * pi * height * (radius1^2 + radius2^2 + (radius1*radius2)) (this is the volume of a frustum!). For each tree I would like to run this equation where height is the height of the cookie plus the heights that came before it (so for tree C1T1 cookie C the height would be 0.91+0.65+0.37) and radius1 is its own radius, radius2 would be the radius of the cookie that comes before it (so again for C1T1 cookie C, radius2 would be the radius of cookie C1T1 B). Additionally for the first "cookie" of each tree - since it has no previous height I would not need to add it to anything, and for the radius2 it could be its own radius used again, so it would be the same value for radius1 and radius2). Any suggestions as to how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems to me you should be using successive differences of height measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~tree, ~cookie, ~height, ~radius1,
  "C1T1", "A", 0.37, 12.3,
  "C1T1", "B", 0.65, 14.2,
  "C1T1", "C", 0.91, 16,
  "C1T2", "A", 0.2, 4,
  "C1T2", "B", 0.5, 10,
  "C1T2", "C", 0.75, 12.4
)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(tree) %>%
  # Sort by height just to be safe
  arrange(tree, height) %>%
  mutate(
    cumheight = cumsum(height),
    radius2 = lag(radius1),
    radius2 = if_else(is.na(radius2), radius1, radius2),
    volume = 1/3 * pi * cumheight * (radius1^2 + radius2^2 + (radius1 * radius2)))
```

Comment: The cookies are sorted in height order if that's what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Since the cookies have to be sorted in height order for the `cumsum()` function to give the right value. Actually, I'll edit the post to include code to sort by height just in case.